# Change GKE cluster node instance type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

How do I change GKE cluster node from `n1-standard-2` to `custom-1-7.5GB` instance? I used terraform to setup the cluster. So I wonder if the cluster needs to be deleted and recreated or if I could change it using `gcloud` and then modify the terraform files to match the current status.

Any suggestion on how do do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools) on GKE, to drain the current one (if you have resource deployed on it) and for GKE to redeploy them on the new node pool, and then delete the useless node pool

Comment: does creating new node pool will automatically drain the current node pool and does GKE  redeploy will automatically happen too?

Comment: No. You can have a cluster with different node pool, with different hardware configuration to be adapted your workload. You can review the K8S design to understand better the principle, and to get example to migrate your pods